# Results from getimagesize (width and height) aren't correct in PHP

Tags: php, height, width, getimagesize

I got a problem with `getimagesize()`. It occurs when I upload an image but.. only sometimes.

The script should check the image size for an avatar (profile-pic). If lower or equals 200px X 200px then it's ok.

I'm not done with the script yet, some security things are missing. But I'm totally confused why this happens and why this only sometimes happens.

My script:

```
//UpdateAvatar
if(isset($_FILES['uploadAvatar']) AND (isset($_SESSION['user']) OR isset($_SESSION['dev']))) {
    //Upload
    $uploadDir = "../img/avatar/";//relative path (we're in php folder [one step back then img])
    $avatarExtension = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadAvatar']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//avatar extension (jpg,png,gif)
    if($avatarExtension == "gif" || $avatarExtension == "jpeg" || $avatarExtension == "jpg" || $avatarExtension == "png") {
        $_FILES['uploadAvatar']['name'] = $LoginName."_avatar".".".$avatarExtension;//build new name (max 4 different avas [png/gif/jpg/jpeg] for one user)
        $uploadFile = $uploadDir.basename($_FILES['uploadAvatar']['name']);//'name' is the key (index) of the array
        $uploadFileRes = getimagesize($uploadFile);//resolutionArray = 0 => width | 1 => height
        if(($uploadFileRes[0] <= 200) && ($uploadFile[1] <= 200)) {//250x250

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadAvatar']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
                //Uploaded
                $newAvatarSql = "UPDATE UserLogIn SET Avatar = '$uploadFile' WHERE ID = '$rcSID'";
                mysql_query($newAvatarSql);
                $Avatar = $uploadFile;
            } else {//UploadFailed
                $ucfg_error_msg = "<span title=\"ServerSide failure\" onClick=\"killErrMsg(this)\" class=\"ucfgErrMsg\">Upload failed!</span>";
            }

        }else {//FileResolution  >(200x200)
            $errImageSize =  $uploadFileRes[0]." x ".$uploadFileRes[1];
            $ucfg_error_msg = "<span title=\"Your Avatar had: $errImageSize\" onClick=\"killErrMsg(this)\" class=\"ucfgErrMsg\">Avatar resolution was<br />greater than 200x200!</span>";
        }
    }else {//NotSupported Extension
        $ucfg_error_msg = "<span title=\"Supported: *.png | *.jpg | *.gif\" onClick=\"killErrMsg(this)\" class=\"ucfgErrMsg\">File-Extension not supported!</span>";
    }
}else {//NotLoggedIn or no Avatar submitted or "fresh Script" => No real error // but blank for JS
    $ucfg_error_msg = "<span class=\"ucfgErrMsg\"></span>";
}
```

Comment: Please always add your code in questions - if the pasteboard goes down, or the paste is deleted, then the question can no longer be read by future readers. There are formatting tools in the editor to render code, as per my edit. We like questions to be read long after the original problem has been solved - sometimes a solution will be useful for more than one person!

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for errors in the upload, this is the first thing you should be looking at when uploading files.

Check/test `$_FILES['uploadAvatar']['error']` before doing anything with the `$_FILES` array.

[See documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: Yes, it's not finished yet. But I think it will be useful to add this :)